# PhoneGap error on deviceready event with HTML 5

Tags: android, html, cordova, simulator

I have the simplest PhoneGap app one could imagine!

All I'm trying to do is show an alert message on deviceready event.

**HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PhoneGap</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="common.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index-page">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**common.js CODE**

```
var isPhoneGapReady = false;
function init() {

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", 
            onDeviceReady, false);

        // Older versions of Blackberry < 5.0 don't support 
        // PhoneGap's custom events, so instead we need to 
        // perform an interval check every 500 milliseconds 
        // to see if PhoneGap is ready.  Once done, the 
        // interval will be cleared and normal processing
        // can begin
        var intervalID = window.setInterval(function() {
              if (PhoneGap.available) {
                  onDeviceReady();
              }
          }, 500);
  }

function onDeviceReady() {
    window.clearInterval(intervalID);

    // set to true
    isPhoneGapReady = true;
alert("The device is now ready");
}

// Set an onload handler to call the init function
window.onload = init;
```

I am using the cloud service to get the APK file and i am running it inside ANdroid simulator version 4.0.3.

**ERROR on console:**

```
init
Ignote this event
W/webcore(6387): java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:1683)
```

I will appreciate if someone could please point out what needs to be done to correct the error.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you're having is that your `intervalID`'s scope doesn't reach your `onDeviceReady()` function. You need to create that function within the `init()` function, like so -

```
var isPhoneGapReady = false;

function init() {

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Older versions of Blackberry < 5.0 don't support 
    // PhoneGap's custom events, so instead we need to 
    // perform an interval check every 500 milliseconds 
    // to see if PhoneGap is ready.  Once done, the 
    // interval will be cleared and normal processing
    // can begin

    var intervalID = window.setInterval(function() {
          if (PhoneGap.available) {
              onDeviceReady();
          }
      }, 500);

        // REMOVE THIS
        // }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.clearInterval(intervalID);

        // set to true
        isPhoneGapReady = true;
    alert("The device is now ready");
    }

// PUT THIS HERE
}

// Set an onload handler to call the init function
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: devicereqady can't happen before window.onLoad.